# Problems with deploying Flask application on Apache 2.4

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, rhel7

I'm trying to deplay my Flask application on a RHEL7 Apache 2.4 server.
File structure is the following inside `/var/www/html`

```
/app
 app.wsgi
  /app
   app.py
   /templates
   /static
```

In my `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` I have the following code to set up my project:

```
    <VirtualHost *>
        ServerName 10.65.112.75:443
        WSGIDaemonProcess app user=apache group=apache threads=5 home=/var/www/html/app/app
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/html/app/app.wsgi

<Directory /var/www/html/app/app/>
        WSGIProcessGroup app
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIScriptReloading On
        Order deny,allow
        Require all granted
</Directory>
        Alias /static /var/www/html/app/app/static/
<Directory /var/www/html/app/app/static/>
        Order deny,allow
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And my `app.wsgi` contains the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/var/www/html/app/app/")
from app import app as application
```

The code for the project itself can be found in my github repository [here](https://github.com/JanSchoenfeld/praxisleistung/tree/master-deutsch).

I do not get any errors when trying to browse the server. It just doesnt do anything. Running my script from the terminal works, though.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There are various things which aren't right.

You have:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/html/app/app.wsgi
```

whereas it appears it should be:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/app/app.wsgi
```

And:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/app/app/>
```

appears it should be:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/app>
```

Your `VirtualHost` definition also looks wrong. You have:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName 10.65.112.75:443
```

If you really want this to be for HTTPS connections, you are missing all the SSL directives to add a SSL certificate.

`ServerName` would also usually be a fully qualified domain name and not an IP:PORT. The port number would usually be in the `VirtualHost` directive. For example, for HTTP, use:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my.host.name
```

where `my.host.name` is the full public host name for your machine which you use in the URL, not an IP address.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I made the changes and left ServerName out because i don't have a domain to use.

When i try to access the site via IP address in my browser it fails to connect, when i use https it tells me i have no right to access the site. I set Require all granted in my <Directory /> previously.

Comment: Did you drop the ``<VirtualHost></VirtualHost>`` as well? Are there any other ``VirtualHost`` definitions in the main Apache config or include from any sites files? If you are not using a hostname and there are other ``VirtualHost`` definitions, Apache will default to using the first it finds.

Comment: We found the problem: I didnt tell the server to listen on port 80 so i added `Listen 12.34.56.78:80`. Since we want it to be https i gotta figure out how to add the directives for the certificates we already have! Thank you so much for the help, though!

Comment: Did you discard the default Apache configuration. Default Apache configuration files would always specify a ``Listen`` for port 80. Also, unless you have a very specific need, you should always listen on all interfaces and not bind it to a specific IP.